# Database structure for handling synonyms in a search engine

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

So I am trying to create an application which has a search element, and I need to figure out a way to handle the data in a smart way in the database.

So of we say that if that foo, bar and bleh are synonyms and a user searches for "foo", the system would then search in the database for entries containing the word "foo" (duh), but it would also look in another table (or something) for synonyms of foo, and when it finds "bar" and "bleh" there it would also look for those when it searches the database.

Which database (Traditional MySQL or noSQL (MongoDB)) would be best for this? And how should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For single-word searches you can maintain a list of synonyms for a given word and then search on those as well. Here's a good way of doing that:[Best way to store and retrieve synonyms in database mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974671/best-way-to-store-and-retrieve-synonyms-in-database-mysql)

When you start talking multi-word searches where each word can have it's own synonyms you're looking at a whole different beast because determining the best match is very difficult. A good search algorithm will use a weighting system to determine the best matches.

IE, if it finds a match on the original keyword in the title, it'll return that before it does a synonym.

Comment: Yes I was thinking something like this, thanks! Now I wish I knew how to actually create a ManyToMany relation with one Model in Django