# Advance searching in MySQL according to synonym words

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, which are below with related details

```
1. Primary words

+----+---------+
| id | word    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Machine |
+----+---------+
| 2  | phone   |
+----+---------+

2. Alternative words    

+----+------------+-----------+
| id | primary_id | word      |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | system    |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 2  | 1          | feature   |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 3  | 2          | telephone |
+----+------------+-----------+

3. product table

+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | mobile system    |
+----+------------------+
| 2  | computer machine |
+----+------------------+
| 3  | wired telephone  |
+----+------------------+
```

Now twist is that whenever user search with "machine" in product table then display results of product with table name have "machine" or "system" or "feature" and if search with "system" or "feature" then also display results of "machine" or "system" or "feature".or vice vera.

Would you please suggest me how can solve this one?

Comment: It would help to show what query you are using. And also, just to be clear: in whatever system you have, the user types "machine", a search is performed (aforementioned db query runs), it returns 3 rows  "machine", "system", "feature"?

Comment: use `id` from first table and `primary_id` from second table?

Comment: Pls show us what you have tried because this is just a code request at the moment.

Comment: Updated my answer with the new requirements... check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking...

**SQL**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Product P
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT fw.Word  --(6) select all products that exist in this query
                FROM (SELECT pw.Word --(1) select all Primary words matching input
                        FROM PrimaryWords pw
                       WHERE pw.Word = 'machine'
                      UNION --(3) union the results from both selects
                      SELECT aw.Word --(2) select all Alternative words that match input or have its primary matching it
                        FROM PrimaryWords pw INNER JOIN AlternativeWords aw
                          ON pw.Id = aw.PrimaryId
                       WHERE pw.Word = 'machine'
                          OR aw.Word = 'machine') as fw --(4) alias the result
                WHERE p.Name LIKE '%' || fw.Word || '%'); -- (5) filter products that match the valid words
```

you can read the comments ordered by the numbering in ().

Comment: Thanks, @DesertFox It is great. But now twist is that I have product table so need to match this one with the product name. Means whenever user will search machine then need to display product related to the machine, system, and feature, which is I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: So, now there is a product table? Mate, you should read your question and update it appropriately.

Comment: Yes, it updated. Please check it and let us know if you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks with your query I have founded first all words and then matched with the product name. But there is I have completed with two queries it would be great if you have an idea with the single query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to take those two table data inti one and then give condition.

```
Select word from(
SELECT id,word FROM PrimaryWords
Union all
Select primaryid,word from AlternativeWords a
) where id in ( select id from primarywords where word='yoursearchketword'
Union
Select primaryid from AlternativeWords where word='yoursearchketword')
```

**Updated Answer as per your product table**.

Now you need to cross join the product table, because there is no relationship between them.

One more thing is you have to use like operator here to compare you desired result with prouct table's name column. Here I have given small idea How to accomplish that, but you can easily improve the same.

```
Select a.word,b.name from
  (Select word from(
    SELECT id,word FROM PrimaryWords
    Union all
    Select primaryid,word from AlternativeWords a
    ) where id in ( select id from primarywords where word='yoursearchketword'
    Union
    Select primaryid from AlternativeWords where word='yoursearchketword')) a, product b
Where a.word LIKE CONCAT('%',name, '%');
```

Comment: Can you please set this one with product table for this scenario "twist is that whenever user search with "machine" in product table then display results of product with table name have "machine" or "system" or "feature" and if search with "system" or "feature" then also display results of "machine" or "system" or "feature".or vice vera."

Comment: Do you have one more table apart from these 2 tables??

Comment: In product table which column will it search for 'machine' word

Comment: What is the relationship between these 2 tables and product table, if it is known then easy to write quert

Comment: no relation with these 2 tables and product table, need to match words which we found in the  2 tables and get products based on this words only.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to put it in one table like this:

```
id | primary_id | word
1 | 1 | machine
2 | 2 | phone
3 | 1 | system
4 | 1 | feature
5 | 2 | telephone
```

And the query will be like this, lets take `machine` word as an example:

```
Select word from MyTable where primary_id in 
             (select primary_id from MyTable where word = "machine")
```

The output: `machine`, `system`, `feature`

---

**Update**

In case you have more columns, for example to show how much related are these words, you can add one more table to map between words, like the following:

```
id | w1_id | w2_id | relation
1 | 1 | 3 | 80
2 | 2 | 5 | 90
3 | 1 | 4 | 60
4 | 3 | 4 | 60
```

And the words table will list only the words like:

```
id| word
1 | machine
2 | phone
3 | system
4 | feature
5 | telephone
```

*In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974671/best-way-to-store-and-retrieve-synonyms-in-database-mysql) you will find a long discussion talking about way you have to design the layout of your schema as well as hints in how retrieve your data.*

Comment: Doesn't matter of table look, thank you for the suggestion. But I think your query is not helpful more me it will return only machines records.

Comment: you can change it as much as you like; you could replace word `machine` with whatever.

Comment: No need to do any relation between tables wich is you have mentioned.

Comment: I answered your first question, not the last updated one!!